# How to save multiple expression in a single file with specified names for the expressions

Tags: export, save

I could not find any reasonable answer for the following question.
(https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/mathematica-output-display.386890/).

I have expressions:

```
f1=1;
f2=20;
```

I want to save them in a single file:

```
PutAppend[f1,f2,"output.m"];
```

This prints all the expression in the output file.
The output of this is:

```
cat output.m
1
20
```

However I was wondering is there any way to print (save) the variable name as well or any customised name. The desired output:

```
f1=1
f2=20
```

or

```
name1=1
name2=20
```

I tried some but those are not useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = {"test"};
bar = Association[];
Save["test.m", {foo, bar}]
FilePrint["test.m"]
```

> ```
> foo = {"test"}
>
> bar = <||>
> ```

You can `Get` the symbols back to the current namespace after you have restarted the `Kernel` or have just removed them once:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
foo
bar
Get["test.m"]
foo
bar
```

> ```
> foo
>
> bar
>
> <||>
>
> {"test"}
>
> <||>
> ```

Comment: This helps.
Save["output.m",f1,f2] will give the desired output, however without customization of the name at the time of printing/saving. Of course one can always change the expression name f1-> name1 and f2-> name2.